# PHP + MongoDB trying to update | cannot use the part (..) to traverse the element

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to update an array stored in mongo, but I'm getting this error `cannot use the part (data of data.info) to traverse the element`. I've tried lot of things and read many other posts but none fits my problem and isn't there enough documentation about how to reach using PHP with the new driver.

I need to add a document inside the array of documents called `info`.

This is what I'm doing in PHP:

```
$conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$options = ["upsert" => true];

$document = ['$push' => ["data.info" => ["user" => "Megan", "hours" => [12, 13]]]];

$filtro = ["year" => 2016, "month" => 5, "day" => 18, "data.room" => 1];

$bulk->update($filtro, $document, $options);
$aux = $conn->executeBulkWrite("prueba.books3", $bulk);
```

Data that I have stored:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("571a0eb07d67f0b82324e683"),
   "year":2016,
   "month":5,
   "day":18,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "room":1,
         "info":[  
            {  
               "user":"Jack",
               "hours":[  
                  10,
                  11,
                  16
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Example of how it should look after the update:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("571a0eb07d67f0b82324e683"),
   "year":2016,
   "month":5,
   "day":18,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "room":1,
         "info":[  
            {  
               "user":"Jack",
               "hours":[  
                  10,
                  11,
                  16
               ]
            },
            {  
               "user":"Megan",
               "hours":[  
                  12,
                  13
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried 
`$document = ['$push' => ["data" => ["info" => ["user" => "Megan", "hours" => [12, 13]]]]];`

Comment: Thanks @domos! It did the trick, more or less, because I can store it but not inside the array `info` which has `"room" => 1` as sibling. It's being stored below that document creating another new one. Given this, I guess that the filter is also bad, so how can I specify correctly the *where clause* `"data.room" => 1`? Thanks so much.